# want to set image url in listview from a function return in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Imagebtn" runat="server" ImageUrl=retriveurl('<%# Eval("id") %>') CommandName="viewalbum" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
<asp:Label ID="product_nameLabel" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("product_name") %>' />
```

i want to set image url from another database table using `Eval("id").query` can return several row.but i want to set the last url from datareader.

Comment: <asp:ImageButton ID="Imagebtn" runat="server" ImageUrl=retriveurl('<%# Eval("id") %>') CommandName="viewalbum" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' />

Comment: You are not asking a question. Try reading your post again. Make it readable. Format the code. Add information that can be used to answer your question, at the very least; what are your results and what was the expected results ?

Comment: You can join your query to that table and retrieve the URL before binding to the ListView. I mean, return the URL with the result from DB before binding to listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind the last url from dataTable you can customize your datasource by calling a separate method which would return you the required url and then the updated datasouce can be binded.

Comment: i have an album table and an images table.i make listview with album table.but i want to set image url from images table that would come with album_id like select image_url from images where album_id=Eval("album_id").how to do that?

Comment: To do so define one method pass the album id, inside that method do custom implementation so that it will return you the last row which you want.

To get the last row you can use Max(image id) or any other criteria to get required output.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM    TABLE
WHERE   ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM TABLE)

this type of query can be used

Comment: <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# retriveurl( Eval("ALBUM_ID")) %>'></asp:ImageButton>
and my codebehind code
protected string retriveurl(Object  obj)
    {
        string id;
        id = (string)obj.ToString();
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("cstr");
        string query = "select IMAGE_PATH from IMAGE_INFO WHERE ALBUM_ID =" + id + "";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return id;
    }
but it does not work.should i consider some event handler?

Comment: 'code'
 protected string retriveurl(Object  obj)
    {
        string id;
        id = (string)obj.ToString();
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"|DataDirectory|\\ImageDB2.mdb\";Persist Security Info=True");
        string query = "select IMAGE_PATH from IMAGE_INFO WHERE ALBUM_ID =" + id + "";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return id;
    }